# Nice Answer / Enlightened badges broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, enlightened-badge, nice-answer

Just looking over users I see user
https://stackoverflow.com/users/557445/rionmonster#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_recent-ansort_votes

The user has 18 Enlightened badges and 23 Nice answer badges, **but only 5 answers with 10 or more votes.** Looking at the links the badges point you to one can easily see that this is completely broken. What gives?

Comment: Probably answers that previously qualified have either been down-voted or deleted (straight deletion or via migration).

Comment: @ChrisF: That is not the case - I don't see down votes on those answers, and the badges do actually lead to existing answers

Comment: In that case - lost votes due to sockpuppet accounts being deleted/merged into his main account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ChrisF is correct: this user had multiple sockpuppet accounts which were used to upvote his answers. When those were merged, the phony votes disappeared, leaving only the badges behind.

Comment: mhh I actually had to google "sockpuppet account" because I didn't know what it meant - so in this case you keep your badges?

Comment: @BrokenGlass - Sort of. The next time you qualify for a badge that you have too many of it isn't actually awarded. So this guy will have to get to 24 nice answers before getting a new badge.

Comment: mmmm... I know the badges stay once you get it, but if you got the badge this way, do you really think the badges should remain? I think not!
I mean, I'm working hard to get a occasional nice answer badge, and I got enlightened only once... this suck-pupet-maker does not deserve that badges more than I, right?

Comment: Probably he used his work mates as the sockpuppet accounts..

Comment: @jachguate: Please tell me "suck-pupet-maker" was a typo :)

Comment: @Bolt, it really was... I mean sock-puppet-maker... :D.  I'm not English native speaker, so I have no idea of what I have done... what is it?

Answer (score 1):

This has now been corrected, the badges they *actually* earned will be restored over the next few hours as the badge cycles re-grant the legitimate ones.